# Why is my list of objects all the same?

Tags: android, object, matrix, arraylist, opengl-es-2.0

I've been making lists of objects for a while now to make multiple objects in the games I program. I haven't had an issue until now. I use a for loop to create 3 objects, give each object its own values, and then add them to the array list. Unfortunately, when I tried this each object had the same values, which I figured out through logs were the values of the last item in the list. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is the code I'm using(I apologize. It's very sloppy, I'm just trying to program the core of this project currently. There is a lot of useless code/poorly programmed code/incorrectly programmed code, I know)

GLCircle.java(the object I want to make multiple of):

```
package com.background.gl.objects;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glDrawArrays;
import static android.opengl.Matrix.multiplyMM;
import static android.opengl.Matrix.setIdentityM;
import static android.opengl.Matrix.translateM;
import static com.background.gl.glcirclebackgroundanimation.Constants.BYTES_PER_FLOAT;

import java.util.Random;

import android.opengl.Matrix;

import com.background.gl.data.VertexArray;
import com.background.gl.glcirclebackgroundanimation.CircleHandler;
import com.background.gl.helper.TextureShaderProgram;

public class GLCircle {
    private static final int POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT = 2;
    private static final int TEXTURE_COORDINATES_COMPONENT_COUNT = 2;
    private static final int STRIDE = (POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT
    + TEXTURE_COORDINATES_COMPONENT_COUNT) * BYTES_PER_FLOAT;

    public static float x;
    public static float y;
    protected static float[] wallBounds;
    protected static boolean positiveX, positiveY;
    public static boolean nullify;
    protected static float xCounter = 0f;
    protected static float yCounter = 0f;
    public static float[] bounds;
    protected Random ran;

    private static final float[] VERTEX_DATA = {
        // Order of coordinates: X, Y, S, T
        // Triangle Fan
        0f, 0f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
        -0.25f, -0.25f, 0f, 0.9f,
        0.25f, -0.25f, 1f, 0.9f,
        0.25f, 0.25f, 1f, 0.1f,
        -0.25f, 0.25f, 0f, 0.1f,
        -0.25f, -0.25f, 0f, 0.9f };

    private final VertexArray vertexArray;

    public GLCircle(float x, float y) {
        vertexArray = new VertexArray(VERTEX_DATA);
        ran = new Random();
        wallBounds = new float[4];
        nullify = false;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void bindData(TextureShaderProgram textureProgram) {
        //Bind the position data to the shader attribute
        vertexArray.setVertexAttribPointer(
            0,
            textureProgram.getPositionAttributeLocation(),
            POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT,
            STRIDE);
        //Bind the texture coordinate data to the shader attribute
        vertexArray.setVertexAttribPointer(
                POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT,
                textureProgram.getTextureCoordinatesAttributeLocation(),
                TEXTURE_COORDINATES_COMPONENT_COUNT,
                STRIDE);
        }

    public void drawCircle() {
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);
    }


    public float getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return this.y;
    }



    public static boolean isPositiveX() {
        return positiveX;
    }



    public static boolean isPositiveY() {
        return positiveY;
    }


    public float[] getBounds(float ranX, float ranY) {
        if(!positiveX) {
            /*if(ranX >= 0f) {
                wallBounds[0] = 1.05f + ranX;
            } else {*/
                this.wallBounds[0] = 1.05f + ranX;
            //}
        } else {
            /*
            if(ranX >= 0f) {
                wallBounds[0] = 1.05f - ranX;
            } else {*/
                this.wallBounds[1] = 1.05f - ranX;
            //}
        }
        if(!positiveY) {
            this.wallBounds[2] = 1.75f + ranY;
        } else {
            this.wallBounds[3] = 1.75f - ranY;
        }

        return this.wallBounds;
    }

    public void setPos(float[] modelMatrix, 
            float[] projectionMatrix, TextureShaderProgram textureProgram,
            int texture, float x, float y) {
        setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
        if(!nullify) 
            translateM(modelMatrix, 0, 0f, 0.01f, 0f);
        else
            translateM(modelMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, 0f);
        final float[] temp = new float[16];
        multiplyMM(temp, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, temp.length);

        textureProgram.useProgram();
        textureProgram.setUniforms(projectionMatrix, texture);
        bindData(textureProgram);

        drawCircle();
    }

    public void draw(float velocity, float[] modelMatrix, 
            float[] projectionMatrix, TextureShaderProgram textureProgram,
                int texture) {
        xCounter+=0.001f;
        setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
        if(-x < -1.75f) {
            translateM(modelMatrix, 0, 0f, 0.001f, 0f);
        } else {
        translateM(modelMatrix, 0, 0f, -0.001f, 0f);
        }
        final float[] temp = new float[16];
        multiplyMM(temp, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, temp.length);

        textureProgram.useProgram();
        textureProgram.setUniforms(projectionMatrix, texture);
        bindData(textureProgram);

        drawCircle();
    }

    public void scaleCircle(float[] modelMatrix, float x, float y, float z) {
        Matrix.scaleM(modelMatrix, 0, x, y, z);
    }

    public void storeResults(float[] results) {
        this.x = results[0];
        this.y = results[1];
    }
}
```

This is how I create the multiple objects:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            GLCircle circle = new GLCircle(generateRanFloats()[0], generateRanFloats()[1]);
            circles.add(circle);
            /*circle[i].x = circle[i].getX();
            circle[i].y = circle[i].getY();
            circle[i].bounds = circle[i].getBounds();*/
        }
```

And this is the generateranFloats() method:

```
public float[] generateRanFloats() {
        ranSignX = ran.nextFloat();
        ranSignY = ran.nextFloat();
        ranSignX = ranSignX > 0.5f? -1:1;
        ranSignY = ranSignY > 0.5f? -1:1;
        ranSignVeloX = ran.nextFloat();
        ranSignVeloY = ran.nextFloat();
        ranX = ran.nextFloat() * 1.05f;
        ranY = ran.nextFloat() * 1.75f;  
        ranX = ranSignX > 0.5? -ranX:ranX;
        ranY = ranSignY > 0.5? -ranY:ranY;
        Log.d("Generated", Float.toString(ranX));
        return new float[] {ranX, ranY};
    }
```

Why do all of the objects contain the same values(such as x and y)?

Comment: Are all your ranXXX variables floats?

Comment: Yes, they are all floats.

Comment: What happens if you debug step by step your `generateRanFloats()` function?

Comment: Step by step? I am already debugging it by logging the numbers generated on each call. Everytime I create a new object I call the method and log the numbers. The numbers are different each time I call it, but when I call circles.get(1).x and circles.get(2).x, they both equal the same number, which is the last generated x float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple

Your x, y variables are declared as `static`, meaning all instances of your object share the same variables.

By the way, this line

```
GLCircle circle = new GLCircle(generateRanFloats()[0], generateRanFloats()[1]);
```

is doing double work, you're calling generateRanFloats twice, and you use half of the generated information every time.

Comment: I have no idea why I put it as static... Thanks. :D And yeah, I realize I call the generation method twice but only use the x or y. I was just trying to see if it would work. Thanks again.