# I have a loop that initializes a list of objects with values, but as soon as it exits the loop the objects become identical

Tags: c#

As the title suggests I am initializing objects in a list through a loop. But they all become identical when the loop exits. I can see during the loop that they are not the same. but when the loop exits they change to the last object entered.

```
public List<ElevationLayout> layoutList = new List<ElevationLayout>();
    public int layoutNumber { get; set; }
    public int worldWidth { get; set; }

    public Random seed { get; set; }
    public XYSize dimLeft { get; set; }


//I have narrowed down the problem to this method
    //==========================================================================================================================================================
    //==========================================================================================================================================================
    //==========================================================================================================================================================

    public void init(World world) {
        dimLeft = new XYSize();
        ElevationLayout layout = new ElevationLayout();
        dimLeft.y = 0;
        dimLeft.x = world.size.x;
        seed = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        worldWidth = (int)((world.size.x / 6.4) + (world.size.x / 64) - 1);
        layoutNumber =  worldWidth + seed.Next(-2, 3);
        for (int i = 0; i < layoutNumber; i++)
        {
            layout.type = seed.Next(0, 2);
            layout.width = (world.size.x / layoutNumber) + seed.Next(0, ((dimLeft.x / layoutNumber) / 2) + 1);

            if (layout.width > dimLeft.x)
            {
                layout.width = dimLeft.x;
            }

            dimLeft.x -= layout.width;
            layout.height = seed.Next(world.size.y / 16, (world.size.y / 4) + 1);

            if (layout.height > dimLeft.y)
            {
                layout.height = dimLeft.y;
            }


            this.layoutList.Add(layout);
            Console.Write(this.layoutList[i].type); // here the objects are different

            if ((world.size.y -= layout.height) > dimLeft.y)
            {
                dimLeft.y = (world.size.y - layout.height);
            }

            if (dimLeft.x <= 0)
            {
                layoutNumber = i;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
                for (int y = 0; y < layoutNumber; y++)
                    Console.Write(this.layoutList[y].type); //but as soon as i exit the loop they are the same
    }

    //==============================================================================================================
    //==============================================================================================================
    //==============================================================================================================
```

Someone had a similar problem here: [Why is my list of objects all the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974013/why-is-my-list-of-objects-all-the-same)
and here: [Why are all the values in my list the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508098/why-are-all-the-values-in-my-list-the-same)

Initially my list of objects was static, but i have since removed that and the problem remains.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you only create one instance of the object before the loop and set the properties of that one object.
Fix:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < layoutNumber; i++)
    {
          ElevationLayout layout = new ElevationLayout();
```

Basically create your object inside the loop, so that on every iteration you allocate a new object.

Comment: thanks that fixed it. Could you explain why that would be a problem if i was changing the value of the object each time then adding it? (As a programming student i'm just curious.)

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx - when you add the object to the list, you're adding a reference to it rather than a copy of it. So you've got a list full of references to a single object (i.e. a single object in memory).

Comment: thanks that makes a lot of sense. I'll read that article(?) you posted.

Answer (score 2):

You're adding the same layout to the list over and over, rather than creating a new instance of layout each time. Move the code to create the layout object inside the loop.